# VueJS 3 - Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object which is already shallowRef

Tags: performance, vuejs3

No information found about this issue

I import the component like this:

```
import waypointref from "./../jobSkillsComponents/waypoint.vue";
```

use it in constant li this:

```
const waypoint = shallowRef(waypointref);
```

and return it with the data:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      components: {
        waypoint,
      }
    };
  },
```

but still get the error that it is reactive, tried with markRaw too....

```
[Vue warn]: Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of `ref`.  Component that was made reactive:  {title: '', description: '', type: 'waypoint', data: ƒ, render: ƒ, …}
```

Do anyone has any idea why is this happening?
Please let me know if I need to provide any other information

Answer (score 0):

if you use component field inside `reactive`, as example: Component you write in a variable, so use:

```
const myView = markRaw(MyComponent);
```

and then you can store it in `reactive` or return as data field.